# Parsing Serialized JSON DataSet using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

and thanks for reading.

I wrote a web service which is called through jsonp, and returns a .Net 3.5 DataSet which I then want to parse using jquery. It appears that the getJson() method is working fine as far as parsing the json goes. The following request -

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:80/ws.asmx/Example?format=json&callback=?",
  function(data) {
    alert(data.d);
  }
);
```

results in -

```
{
  "Tables": [
      {
        "Rows": [
            {
              "CASE_TYP_CD": "M",
              "CASE_TYP_DESC": "MOVING VIOLATION",
              "AUTO_GENERATE": "Y",
              "CONFIDENTIAL_FLG": "N"
            },
            {
              "CASE_TYP_CD": "T",
              "CASE_TYP_DESC": "TRUANCY/FAILURE TO ATTEND SCHOOL",
              "AUTO_GENERATE": "Y",
              "CONFIDENTIAL_FLG": "N"
            },
            {
              "CASE_TYP_CD": "J",
              "CASE_TYP_DESC": "JUVENILE",
              "AUTO_GENERATE": "Y",
              "CONFIDENTIAL_FLG": "N"
            }...
```

Well I'm kind of new at this whole json thing and I can't figure out how to gain access to the values held in the nodes.

I was thinking it would be something like -

```
$.each("CASE_TYP_CD", function() { //code goes here });
```

But that doesn't seem to be working.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.com!

Comment: As an aside, JSON has native boolean types - they'd might be a better match for your "CONFIDENTIAL_FLG" and "AUTO_GENERATE" fields if your only values are "Y" and "N"...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up on general JavaScript object literals (which are very similar to JSON).

What I see from JSON, to get the value of CASE_TYP_CD in the first row of the first table you
write

```
var result = <json>;
var val result.Table[0].Rows[0].CASE_TYP_CD;
```

is that what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 0):

here's how you would iterate through your object with $.each():

```
$.each(data.d.Tables, function(index, table) {
    $.each(table.Rows, function(index, row) {
        alert(row.CASE_TYP_CD);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure something is up with the way the DataSet is being serialized in my web service.

Whenever I try a method, including the ones that have been suggested here I get two javascript errors -

```
Message: 'length' is null or not an object
Line: 29
Char: 452
Code: 0
URI: js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js
```

and

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: /GetCaseTypes?format=json&callback=jsonp1273246775675
```

Thank you for all your suggestions but it looks like my problem lies within the serialization of the DataSet and not in my jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, apparently the getJson method wasn't actually parsing the json string into a java object like it should have been. I simply had to add

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);
alert(obj.Table[0].CASE_TYP_CD);
```

and everything worked as expected.

Thanks to everyone who posted here.